# Conditional property in wix script

Tags: wix, conditional-statements

I used the below property so i could avoid the add or remove option in the control panel

```
 <Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" Value="1" />
```

But i need to make it dynamic .I want to read the value in the registry. If a value mathes my condition i will include this orelse i wont include this line my partial code is as follows

```
<Property Id="NETFRAMEWORK20">
    <RegistrySearch Id="NetFramework20"
                    Root="HKLM"
                    Key="Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v2.0.50727"
                    Name="Install"
                    Type="raw" />
</Property> 

//Some Conditon

<Condition Message="I will create the Add or remove option since the softwar i look for s not present">
    <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK20]]>
</Condition>
<Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" Value="1" />

//or else
```

Thank in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [`SetProperty`](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/setproperty.html). Means, instead of:

```
<Property Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" Value="1" />
```

try:

```
<SetProperty Id="ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT" After="InstallInitialize" Value="1">
    <![CDATA[~~~CONDITION~~~]]>
</SetProperty>
```

As a side note, I would recommend first, not to hide staff you install from add/remove, and second, [use standard .NET framework extension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/check_for_dotnet.html) for checking if .NET framework is installed instead of inventing your own method with registry search.

Comment: Thank yew nikolay. I am new to wix. I want to add minor updates like adding some changed files to my already installed application. Can you suggest me the best way to do it

Comment: Sorry, can't help you here. As of my experience, minor updates / patches is sort of a grey area of windows installer. Don't do that, unless you really must (like if your installation is hundreds of megabytes). Do a simple major update instead).